# Update items in listbox2 as items in listbox 1 remove or added

Tags: vb6

I want listbox 2 automatically updated as items in listbox 1 remove or added.. Listbox1 & listbox 2 in different form... Listbox1 in form 1 and listbox 2 in form2.. I want there will be a connection between the two listbox.. Currently using vb6.0. Anyone know how? Thanks..

Comment: This question is too broad. A broad answer: handle change events on one listbox and update the other from the event handler. Bonus opinion: it's 2015. VB6 came out in 1998. Visual Studio Express is free. Please, upgrade to VB.NET (or C#!).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sub that is used to update the listboxes. For example, adding a new item would look something like this.

```
Public Sub AddListItem(ByVal str As String)
    Form1.List.AddItem str
    Form2.List.AddItem str
End Sub
```

Utilize a similar concept for removing list items.